# getting errors when combining these 2 sql queries

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this

```
$sql_totalbooknumber =  "SELECT SUM(items_counter) FROM probid_categories WHERE items_counter>0 AND `category_id <>355";
$sql_updatebooknumber = "UPDATE `probid_categories` SET `items_counter` = ".$sql_totalbooknumber." WHERE  `category_id` =  '355'";


            if (!mysql_query($sql_totalbooknumber))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  };
            if (!mysql_query($sql_updatebooknumber))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  };
```

somehow they work fine individually (if i comment out one or the other) but when I combine them I get this error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(items_counter) FROM probid_categories WHERE items_counter>0 AND `cate' at line 1

Comment: AND \`category_id remove the \`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sql_totalbooknumber` is a string with your query in it.  Not the results of that query.

You're expecting an integer to be passed in to `$sql_updatebooknumber`, but you're passing the string that contains your first query into it.

Try this:

```
$sql_totalbooknumber =  "SELECT SUM(items_counter) FROM probid_categories WHERE items_counter>0 AND `category_id` <>355";
$result = mysql_query($sql_totalbooknumber);
list($id) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sql_updatebooknumber = "UPDATE `probid_categories` SET `items_counter` = ".$id." WHERE  `category_id` =  '355'";
mysql_query($sql_updatebooknumber);
```

Comment: @andrewsi has a single-pass solution to this that is also less...[SQL-injectionny](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: He's not passing any user input in, so there's no risk of SQL Injection.  Unless the `355` is user input.

Comment: Oh gotcha, I didn't realize he was trying to do a subquery.

Comment: Any data should be escaped. You start to assume and you eventually make serious mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a subquery; you really need to wrap it in brackets:

```
$sql_totalbooknumber =  "SELECT SUM(items_counter) FROM probid_categories WHERE items_counter>0 AND `category_id` <>355";
$sql_updatebooknumber = "UPDATE `probid_categories` SET `items_counter` = (".$sql_totalbooknumber.") WHERE  `category_id` =  '355'";
```

Otherwise, the database can't parse it properly.

Comment: You're missing a backtick by category_id

Comment: i get You can't specify target table 'probid_categories' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @AdamPlocher - Well-spotted. Thank you! (Though I did take that from the question - I wonder if that might also not be helping with the code not working?)

Comment: i added the back-tick already, i think this applies http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/ for this error because i had this yesterday

Comment: I'm at the limit of my knowledge of subqueries - have you tried the answer from @AdamPlocher ?

Comment: That error might be because you're doing a subquery off the same table you're updating (I'm not positive, it actually looks like it should work).  Try the code I posted below and see if that helps at all.  It's not as clean as andrewsi's solution, but it might do the trick.